# Improper integral - Calculating Area of Floor Function

Tags: calculus, area

I'm stuck trying to calculate the area of the region defined by:

$\begin{Bmatrix}
{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:0\leq x\wedge 0\leq y\leq 2^{-\lfloor x \rfloor}}
\end{Bmatrix}$

I'm just starting studying Calculus I and I don't have much information to give: I could do this exercise if it wasn't for $x\leq0$, however I can't calculate the improper integral because I can't integrate the floor function and I though about using an infinite sum (I don't know if that doesn't make sense) but we haven't started learning it yet so I assume that ain't it.

Comment: I guess you mean $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @ajotatxe You're right, I tried to give more information on my situation.

Comment: @MPW Thanks, just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we plot y against x, $[x]$ is the floor function with steps going upward.  However the function $y = 2^{-[x]}$ has steps going downward with each step half of the height before it.  Hence if $N <= x < N + 1$ we have area equal to

$$\int2^{-[x]}dx = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{(N - 1)}} + \frac{1}{2^N}(x - N)$$

$$= \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2^N}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2^N}(x - N) = 2 - \frac{1}{2^N}(2 - (x - N))$$

$$= 2 - \frac{1}{2^{[x]}}(2 - x + [x])$$

Since N = [x].

Comment: To include more than 1 character in superscript, you have to close it using braces. For example, $2^{n-1}$ `$2^{n-1}$`.